# Не валидный DKIM

Tags: email, postfix, dkim

opendkim.conf

```
AutoRestart Yes
AutoRestartRate 10/1h
Mode sv
Syslog yes
SyslogSuccess yes
LogWhy yes
UserID opendkim:opendkim
Socket inet:8891@localhost
PidFile /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid
Umask 0002
Canonicalization relaxed/relaxed
Selector default
MinimumKeyBits 1024
KeyFile /etc/postfix/dkim/mail.mysite.com.private
KeyTable /etc/postfix/dkim/keytable
SigningTable refile:/etc/postfix/dkim/signingtable
ExternalIgnoreList  refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
InternalHosts   refile:/etc/opendkim/TrustedHosts
```

/etc/default/opendkim

```
SOCKET="inet:8891@localhost"
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 2
```

Лог файл

```
 opendkim[12911]: 97DA920DAA: DKIM-Signature field added (s=mail, d=eyesrocket.tk)
```

Gmail

```
dkim=fail header.i=@mysite.com header.s=mail header.b=Sg/vCyMW;
```

подскажите что нужно сделать чтобы DKIM заработал, уже весь инет перерыл и перепробовал, ничего не работает

Comment: DNS-запись добавить не забыли?

Comment: Dns записи все на месте, на валид проверил.

Comment: Все решил вопрос, Приватный ключ бел сгенерирован ошибкой изза того что servername у vps провайдера был прописан не мой а их внутренний!